# SWF loading SWF not Connecting to Internet

Tags: apache-flex, flash

So I'm building a master swf file that contains 3 other swf files.
The 3 that live in the master one need to connect to the internet using a 
proxy + url + nocache

Locally each of the 3 work fine also when I make/compile the master swf file that contains the other 3 it also works fine.
but when I put it on our player which using the proxy it gives me a sandbox error 2048.

Please advice.
thank you.

EDIT:
Locally Means : when I compile and debug or when I open the swf in a browser on my machine ( it works)

Put it on our player: we have a player that is LINUX based, that takes the master swf file and runs it in a browser using a proxy.

ErrorType: SecurityError- bubble:false - cancel:false - EventPhase:2 - Error#2048

Yes One of the 3 swf files tries to get a twitter feed and I have added Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.twitter.com/crossdomain.xml") to the master swf that runs all 3 and the one that is specific to twitter.

Comment: When you say "locally" do you mean on a web server running on your development machine?  Or do you mean you are opening the SWF files using a URL that points to a directory on your local machine?  I also don't understanding what "put it on our player" means.  Do you mean uploading the SWF files to a web server?   can you provide the full error you are seeing?  Are you accessing files between separate domains?  If so, do you have a crossdomain.xml file in place?

Comment: I have answered your questions in an edit.
thanks